# Client validation doesn't show message when use EditorFor for List<T>

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model, simple:

```
public class MyModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MyValidation]
    public CheckBoxModel IList<Options> { get; set; }
}
```

the `CheckBoxModel` is:

```
public class CheckBoxModel {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

And `MyValidation` class:

```
public class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules( ModelMetadata metadata,
         ControllerContext context )
      {
         yield return new ModelClientValidationRule {ValidationType = "requiredgroup"};
      }

public override bool IsValid( object value )
      {
         // logic here
      }
}
```

Ok, let's show you also the views:

```
<div class="test">
   @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Options)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Options)
</div>
```

The editor template looks like `CheckBoxModel.cshtml`:

```
<div>
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsChecked, new {data_val_requiredgroup = "One item should be checked"})
   ...
</div>
```

The generated HTML by `EditorFor` looks like

```
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="Options[0].IsChecked" name="Options[0]_IsChecked" data-val-required-group="One item should be checked"/>
</div>
```

the custom javascript validation:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredgroup', {}, function (options) {
   options.rules['requiredgroup'] = true;
   options.messages['requiredgroup'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod('requiredgroup', function(value, element, params) {
   var $module = $(element).parents('form');
   var result = $module.find('input[type="checkbox"][data-val-requiredgroup]:checked').length;

   return result;
});
```

The client validation works (the form submit is canceled and stay on same page) but it didn't display the error.

How to achieve this? How to display error message in `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Options)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your custom validation class needs to inherit from the ValidationAttribute class, and pass the error message to the base constructor.

```
public class DummyAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public DummyAttribute() : base("{0} contains invalid data.")
    ....
}
```

Comment: I changed from `Required` to `ValidationAttribute` ... same thing

Comment: If you inspect the html of the rendered page, can you see your validation message for the specific property in a data- attribute?

Comment: I have a `<span>` tag from `   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Options)` ... but the data attribute name is not match with the elements rendered by `EditorFor`

Comment: try to add an error message to the ModelClientValidationRule
yield return new ModelClientValidationRule {ValidationType = "requiredgroup",  ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage};

Comment: I tried also with `ErrorMessage` but ... same issue.

Comment: I would suggest you to try creating a validation attribute for a simple type (ex: int) to check wether ther problem is caused by something else in your project.